# Dynamically add jars to SpringBoot at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot 1.4.2. I want to be able to launch my SpringBoot application from the command line, specifying additional, external jars that should also be component scanned at the time I launch the application. I can't use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` because I won't have the spring boot application's pom when I want to launch it.

I have tried the following so far, where `my-jar.jar` is the spring boot application and `external-jar.jar` is the external jar I want to include on the command line:

```
java -cp my-jar.jar -Dloader.path=external-jar.jar -Dloader.main=com.my.Application org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

This launches but does not component scan `external-jar.jar`

```
java -cp external-jar.jar:my-jar.jar -Dloader.main=com.my.Application org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

This fails to launch, saying `@Autowired` conditions in `external-jar.jar` were not satisfied, even though classes in `my-jar.jar` do satisfy them. I have tried reversing the order of the jars on the classpath, this doesn't fix the issue.

```
java -Dloader.path="external-jar.jar" -jar my-jar.jar
```

This launches but does not component scan `external-jar.jar`

My component scanning path at the top of my SpringApplication class has a package paths for both `my-jar.jar` and `external-jar.jar` and I have verified that when referencing `external-jar.jar` directly within my pom it is component scanned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the wrong launcher. Support for `loader.path` and `loader.main` is provided by `PropertiesLauncher` but you're using `JarLauncher`.

Comment: I honestly cannot thank you enough! `java -cp my-jar.jar -Dloader.path=external-jar.jar -Dloader.main=com.my.Application org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` works

Comment: Thanks man! You also made my day! I've struggle with this for a few hours...